# Convert the string into dictionary value in jquery and json

Tags: jquery, json

I need to convert the below string "{'id':1,'name':'Sindhuja','address':'Coimbatore'}" into dictionary in jquery.

Comment: what you exactly required pleas specify

Comment: And what is `dictionary` here?

Comment: I need js dictionary....Example i'm getting the data as "{'id':1,'name':'Sindhuja','address':'Coimbatore'}" but my required output to be {'id':1,'name':'Sindhuja','address':'Coimbatore'}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JSON.parse` is built into JavaScript.  Additionally, JSON only accepts `"`, not `'`; so, I added a replace function call.

```
<script>
di = JSON.parse("{'id':1,'name':'Sindhuja','address':'Coimbatore'}".replace(/'/g,"\""));
console.log(di);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var obj = JSON.parse(str.replace(/'/g, '"'));
```

Just convert it into an Object.

Comment: Now single-quotes in string will be converted to double-quotes and invalid json can be fixed.